# Upload a file using an API PUT request

Tags: php, curl, upload, request, put

I'm building an API in PHP. One of the methods is place.new (PUT request). It expects several string fields, and it also expects an image. However I can't get it working. With a POST request it was easy, but I'm not sure how to do it with a PUT and how to get the data on the server.

thanks for the help!

#### Test CURL code

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $image);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($image));

$this->result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

#### Server code

```
if ( $im_s = file_get_contents('php://input') )
{
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($im_s);

    if ( $image != '' )
    {
        $filename = sha1($title.rand(11111, 99999)).'.jpg';
        $photo_url = $temp_dir . $filename;
        imagejpeg($image, $photo_url);

        // upload image
        ...
    }
}
```

## Solution

#### send

```
// Correct: /Users/john/Sites/....
// Incorrect: http://localhost/...
$image = fopen($file_on_dir_not_url, "rb");

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $image);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_on_dir_not_url));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

#### receive

```
/* Added to clarify, per comments */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen($photo_url, "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
    and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
{
    fwrite($fp, $data);
}

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
```

Comment: i think something is missing in the receive part:     $putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you read http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php ? `Script PUT /put.php` all set up?

Also, what is `$image` -- it needs to be a file handler, not a file name.

Ps. Using `file_get_contents` will try to load whatever is PUT on the server into memory. Not a good idea. See the linked manual page.

Comment: thanks! I didn't arrive to that page searching on Google before. Joining that information with some answers from SO, i got it working :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the working solution but the receive code misses the initialization of `$putdata`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't populate form data in `PUT` requests (either in `PATCH`).

Just install https://pecl.php.net/package/apfd and `PATCH` and `PUT` request will have `$_POST` and `$_FILES` as if were `GET` or `POST` requests.

In Docker it will be:

```
RUN pecl install --force apfd && rm -rf /tmp/pear && docker-php-ext-enable apfd
```