# What is Php's equivalent of Java's newInputStreamSupplier?

Tags: php, file, curl, put

I have been trying to implement a functionality that is written in Java, for uploading a file via PUT HTTP request.

Here is my sample Java code:

```
import com.google.common.io.Files;

public void uploadFile() {
        final makeRestRequest makeUploadRequest = makeRequestTo(upload_file_location)
                .method("PUT")
                .addHeader(new HttpHeader("Accept", "application/json"))
                .addHeader(new HttpHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip"))
                .body(Files.newInputStreamSupplier(new java.io.File("/sample_file.zip")))
                .build();

        final getRestResponse uploadResponse = makeUploadRequest.fetchResponse();
}
```

I am looking for a similar variant of the php code, that can make a HTTP PUT call to upload a file, but i am not sure what to use for the **newInputStreamSupplier**. Here is my sample php code, that makes a PUT call to upload file using CURL, but fails to get a response:

```
<?php
$url = upload_file_location; 
$localfile = "sample_file.zip";

$fp = fopen ($localfile, "rb"); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/zip';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile)); 
$http_result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

I get an error saying: "File content is empty". Does anyone have an idea of what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error? Or are you just asking what the file stream is? If you're just asking what the file stream is, where did you get the code from? Also, are you specifically trying to do a PUT? Or a POST? You're not specifying PUT anywhere that I can see.

Comment: I am getting error saying: File Content is empty. I got the sample java code from an application that is able to successfully make a PUT call. I am supposed to mimic that call with php.

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-getinfo.php to get more info

Comment: Check the return value from `fopen()`. Try giving the full path to the input file.

Comment: What line of code is the error associated with? What does the remote server see? If you can't get that info, can you change the URL and test on a local server?

Comment: Also, where is the file located? You've not specified any path.

Comment: When i print the $http_result, i get the error saying File content is empty. The file is located in the same folder as the php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i figured out a solution for my question.
I should pass the full path to the file in the CURL filesize header:

**`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize(realpath($localfile));`**

Also, I had to add the below CURL header to transfer file data as binary:

**`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);`**

The solution mentioned in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6081131/386579) helped me.